# Hibernate: Details of Proxy Implementation (Lazy Fetching)

Tags: hibernate, proxy, fetch, lazy-evaluation

I've learned that Hibernate does not return an instance of your actual entity class when it gives you the result of a query, but instead returns a 'proxy' instance that is dynamically sub-classed from your actual entity's class. I understand the reason for this behaviour, being that it allows for the realization of the lazy initialization. However, I have a few questions left unanswered on the details of the implementation of these proxy classes:

1. Will the lazy fetched field get loaded ONLY when I use the getter? What if I use the field in, say, my `equals` or `hashCode` method? Will the execution of these methods result in a `NullPointerException` when I have not called the getter of this field before?
2. How exactly does Hibernate initialize the field when its initialization is triggered? Does it execute the field's setter method that I have defined in the entity class, or will it assign the value directly to the variable, via reflection or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

First, two rules:

1. Proxies delegate **all** non-final method calls to the target instance, except the method for getting id if property access for id is defined in the mappings.
2. Proxy object instances are **never** initialized, the target instance is initialized.

**1)** Suppose that you invoke `a.equals(b)` where both `a` and `b` are proxies of the same entity. And lets say that `equals` method is implemented like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
  ...
  if (this.someField.equals(other.someField)) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

The `equals` method of `a` is delegated to the target instance forcing its full initialization. So you are safe regarding the fields in the `a` instance (you can use them directly).

However, accessing the fields directly in the `b` instance (`other.someField`) is **never** valid. It does not matter whether `b` is initialized or not, proxy instance is never initialized, only the target instance. So, `someField` is always `null` in the `b` instance.

The correct implementation is to use getters at least for `other` instance:

```
this.someField.equals(other.getSomeField())
```

or to be consistent:

```
this.getSomeField().equals(other.getSomeField())
```

Things are different when it comes to `final` methods - Hibernate can't override them to delegate the call to the target. So, if the `equals` method were `final` in the previous example, you would get a `NullPointerException` when accessing `this.someField`.

All of this can be avoided by configuring Hibernate to use bytecode instrumentation instead of proxies, but that has its own pitfalls and is not adopted widely.

**2)** Again, it never initializes the proxy instance itself. When it comes to the target instance initialization, it depends whether field or property access is defined in the mappings. In both cases reflection is used (to assign values directly to fields in case of field access or to invoke setters in case of property access).